# Installing a BLAS implementation on CentOS 6.4 (Cloudera VM)

Tags: centos, cloudera, blas, nd4j, dl4j

I'm using deeplearning4j and eclipse on CentOS 6.4 (x86_64).

I have downloaded and tried to install intel MKL, OpenBLAS and ATLAS.

Yet I'm still getting this error when I run my program:

> Mar 23, 2016 5:58:04 AM com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS
>
> WARNING: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
>
> Mar 23, 2016 5:58:04 AM com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS
>
> WARNING: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>
> ...

I found answers online talking about installing gfortran >4.7 but I failed.